# How to change encrypted password in context file without using the studio

Tags: encryption, passwords, talend

I am using a group context to configure the db connection. The password of the db has a password type. When deploying the job, the password is automatically encrypted in the default.properties under the contexts folder.
What if i want to change the password without using the studio (on a client environment)? what can i use to encrypt the new password?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to do it by creating a separate encryption job with a tjava component and the following code:

```
System.out.println(routines.system.PasswordEncryptUtil.encryptPassword(context.Password));
```

where context.Password is an input context variable of type String. When running the job, the user is prompted to enter a password and then the encrypted Talend password will be printed. It will have the following format: enc:routine.encryption.key.v1:[encryptedPassword]  The routine encryption key can be modified if needed by following this link: https://help.talend.com/r/en-US/8.0/installation-guide-data-integration-windows/rotating-encryption-keys-in-talend-studio

Answer (score 1):

There's actually a few ways for this:

myJob.sh --context_param myPassword=pass123

this unfortunately can be seen by anyone via ps / task manager.

You can also edit the contexts/contextName.properties file and change the context parameters there. This way the context can only be seen if you have access to the file.

Theoretically both should be able to accept the cleartext/encrypted password.

Implicit context load feature can also be used to load contexts: https://help.talend.com/r/en-US/8.0/data-integration-job-examples/creating-job-and-defining-context-variables